# Laravel - syntax error, unexpected ';' in blade

Tags: forms, laravel-4, syntax-error, laravel-blade

I have a problem with blade. I check if user is log in. If is I pass in two input default value from $user ($user->UserName and $user->UserEmail), if not I pass Input::old().

Before I don't check if user is log in it worked fine. Any suggestions??

The view:

```
@if($errors->has())
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li class="txt-danger">{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif

@if(Session::has('message'))
    <ul>
        <li class="txt-success">{{ Session::get('message') }}</li>
    </ul>
@endif

{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'contact', 'name'=>'contactform', 'id'=>'contactform')) }}
    <p>
        @if(Auth::check())
            {{ Form::text('name', $user->UserName, array('id'=>'name') }}
        @else
            {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('id'=>'name', 'placeholder'=>'Twoje imię')) }}
        @endif
    </p>
    <p>
        @if(Auth::check())
            {{ Form::text('email', $user->UserEmail, array('id'=>'email') }}
        @else
            {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('id'=>'email', 'placeholder'=>'Twój e-mail')) }}
        @endif
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ Form::text('subject', Input::old('subject'), array('id'=>'subject', 'placeholder'=>'Temat')) }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ Form::textarea('message', Input::old('message'), array('id'=>'message', 'placeholder'=>'Wiadomość', 'rows'=>'0')) }}
    </p>
    {{ Form::submit('Wyślij wiadomość', array('class'=>'mainBtn', 'id'=>'submit')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Does the error tell you what line it thinks the `;` is appearing in?

Comment: I found this. It is my stupid mistake. In input after if(Auth:check()) closure missing ")".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the `Input` facade within your form.

The input facade is used to get the values passed by the form once you've submitted it. If you're wanting to use old values being passed back from the controller back to the form you need to pass those as parameters from the controller. Something like:

```
return View::make('MyView')->with('old', $oldValues);
```

The reason you're getting the error "syntax error, unexpected ';' in blade" is because you're using the double curly brace `{{ }}` when you output the `Form::text()` AND you're using the `Input` facade within it, so what php is seeing is something like:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='email'> valuefrominput;</input>";
```

Basically, `Input::old()` is writing a semicolon in the middle of your `Form::text()` code.

Comment: I found this. It is my stupid mistake. In input after if(Auth:check()) closure missing ")".

Comment: Ah, well I'm glad you found it!